# Swift screenshot image resolution bad with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: ios, swift

I have a long calendar screen scrolling and trying to share a full screenshot of the full calendar, used this extension but getting bad image quality of 202x1024 on iPhone 8 plus real device. How can I get a full resolution screenshot including the scrolling area of the screen.

```
fileprivate extension UITableView {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage? {
        let savedContentOffset = contentOffset
        let savedFrame = frame

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentSize)
        contentOffset = .zero
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

        layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        frame = savedFrame

        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying scale for your image context?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
```

Comment: Even simpler: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0)`, From the docs: *"If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen."*.